# zsh vi mode status line

Tags: bash, vi, zsh

Is there a way in zsh or bash to have a status line? e.g. in VI it will let you know that you are in insert mode with
-- INSERT --

Is there an eqivalent for the command line?

Comment: [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039713/different-bash-prompt-for-different-vi-editing-mode)

Answer (score 21):

This has already been answered at [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/151803/how-do-i-customize-zshs-vim-mode) and [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547/make-my-zsh-prompt-show-mode-in-vi-mode). For the completeness of Stack Overflow:

```
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    RPS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/-- NORMAL --}/(main|viins)/-- INSERT --}"
    RPS2=$RPS1
    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

And if you want the indicator below the current line rather than to the right, from [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/is-it-possible-to-display-stuff-below-the-prompt-at-a-prompt):

```
terminfo_down_sc=$terminfo[cud1]$terminfo[cuu1]$terminfo[sc]$terminfo[cud1]
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    PS1_2="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/-- NORMAL --}/(main|viins)/-- INSERT --}"
    PS1="%{$terminfo_down_sc$PS1_2$terminfo[rc]%}%~ %# "
    zle reset-prompt
}
preexec () { print -rn -- $terminfo[el]; }
```

Comment: hmmmm... Now I want to make it so that ctrl+c while in -- INSERT -- doesn't quit the command, but exits to NORMAL mode, then finally ctrl-c in NORMAL mode to exit the command.

Comment: You can set different bindings for Ctrl+C in insert and normal mode, just pass the right option to `bindkey`.

Comment: Sweeet. I can't wait to do this.

Comment: How can I use the second one (where the indicator is below) with a prompt that I already have? Where would I put my existing $PROMPT variable? I've tried it but then the label doesn't update between INSERT and NORMAL when switching modes.

Comment: @user779159 Put your stuff in `PS1`. You need to use either `PROMPT` or `PS1`, they're aliases.

Comment: I am using a ZSH theme that has already generated a nice looking prompt. But when I try adding that $PROMPT variable to the PS1= assignment, it doesn't work properly to update the NORMAL/INSERT values. I can't tell what part of '%~ %# ' at the end to replace with $PROMPT, I've tried several combinations and they don't work. Could you tell me where I could put $PROMPT in that second line? Thanks

Comment: @user779159 That depends on what your theme is doing. Try using `PROMPT` instead of `PS1`, maybe `PROMPT="%{$terminfo_down_sc$PS1_2$terminfo[rc]%}$PROMPT"`. Depending on the theme, you may have to add that bit somewhere else. If you can't figure it out, ask on [unix.se].