# Bash 5 readline vim mode prefixes not showing

Tags: bash, macos, vim, readline

`.inputrc` commands `vi-cmd-mode-string` and `vi-ins-mode-string` are not working. No prefix is shown at the beginning of the bash prompt. But the input mode is indeed vim (I can switch between command / insert mode).

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.1. I've installed `bash` with `brew install bash` (also tested `brew install --HEAD` to compile locally).

My bash version is 5.0.11. Should be enough for `vi-ins|cmd-mode-string` that is available since bash 4.4 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614367/2058840)

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I've also install `readline` via brew, but this changes nothing.

My `.inputrc` :

```
$if Bash
    set editing-mode vi
$endif

$if mode=vi
    set show-mode-in-prompt on
    set vi-cmd-mode-string bbbbb
    set vi-ins-mode-string aaaaa
$endif
```

What am I missing here? With this bash version, I expect `bbbb` or `aaaa` to be shown as the bash prompt prefix.

Comment: The reference to Catalina means I have to ask: are you sure you are *running* `bash`, and not `zsh`? The `.inputrc` works fine for me.

Comment: Yes. `echo $0` outputs `-bash`

Comment: Not on Catalina, but i have bash 5 and dont have this issue. That said, i dont use the conditionals.

Comment: Thans @D.BenKnoble. Just tested without  the conditionals. Same results.

Comment: Ive got 5.0.9; are you youre reloading the inputrc? Does this happen after you eg start a new shell?

Comment: I'm sure the `inputrc` is loaded. When it's empty and I open a new shell, I'm not in vi mode anymore.

Comment: Just tested compiling bash from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Installing-Bash.html. With this compiled version, I see the proper `vi-cmd-mode-string`. Will look at what compilation flag could be missing with the homebrew install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Just found out it's not a problem with the homebrew bash version.

My macOS user config still use the default bash version `/bin/bash` (bash 3) instead of the homebrew one `/usr/local/bin/bash`. 
You can change yours with https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/.

It took me time to understand that because of the `bash --version` test. This test the version of the first bash accessible in your `$PATH`. Not the bash used to open your shell.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes `$SHELL --version` is more enlightening