# Change cursor style for terminal with vim keybinding

Tags: bash, vim, terminal, key-bindings

As some of you guys know, you could access the vim keybindings in the terminal by modifying a ~/.bashrc or ~/.inputrc file. ([Info here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal))

Hence, your terminal has an insert and normal mode, similar to vim. However, I don't know when I'm typing in insert nor normal mode while using my terminal.

Is there a way you could change the terminal's cursor so you know which mode you're in? (You can already [do this in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor).)

Note: I am currently using iterm2 on my mac, and I am using bash, not zsh.

Comment: You might be able to do something by binding the mode switching keys to switching mode and sending the right escape sequences but I'm not in a position to try it at the moment.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, if you hit escape more than once to enter normal mode, then your cursor will think that it is in insert mode instead of normal mode.

Comment: I don't think I understood that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039713/different-bash-prompt-for-different-vi-editing-mode.

Comment: Thank you for the link, @FDinoff. Based on your link, I just upgraded my bash to 4.3, and made my ~/.inputrc file look like this: https://github.com/hlin117/dotfiles/blob/master/.inputrc However, this doesn't fix the problem. Would you know why?

Comment: The user here seems to have the feature working: https://gist.github.com/ethagnawl/86a0284c990196ae31b7. I also commented out line 28 here, but there was no change: https://github.com/hlin117/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc

Comment: @hlin117 it doesn't change the cursor but it shows a `+` at the beginning of the line when it is in insert mode and `:` when in normal mode. (Sorry I didn't make this clear earlier). But opening a new shell should make it show up.

Comment: @FDinoff: I tried opening a new terminal, but there's no indication of a + or : symbol anywhere near my prompt.

Comment: @hlin117 I don't know. Something is misconfigured... Make sure you are really running bash 4.3 (`echo $BASH_VERSION`). They inputrc looked fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for your quick follow ups, @FDinoff. It seems that `bash --version` is returning `4.3.30`, but `echo $BASH_VERSION` is returning `3.2.43`. I'm looking into this issue right now.

Comment: Yes, with some quick poking around, the feature is working, @FDinoff. (I followed all of the steps in the first link you posted.) Thank you!

Comment: Vi key-bindings are not as useful as they seem to be, if only because of the nature of the command-line: a place where you *insert* text. If you seriously need more editing capabilities use a real editor with `<C-x><C-e>`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42107711/52817